# Distributing WebSocket tasks across processes based on CPU cores

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I have a Python script that subscribes to a number of WebSocket feeds using ccxt. I want to distribute these tasks across multiple processes based on the number of CPU cores available, with each process running a single event loop.

Currently, I have a function subscribe_orderbook that subscribes to a WebSocket feed and updates an order book in real-time. I use asyncio.run to run this function in a separate process for each symbol.
kraken_config.json :

```
{
    "AUD/USD": 0,
    "AUD/JPY": 1
}
```

Here's my code:

```
import ccxt.pro
import ccxt
import json
import asyncio
import multiprocessing as mp
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient, NewTopic
from kafka import KafkaProducer

def json_serializer(data):
    return json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8")

async def subscribe_orderbook(symbol,symbols_partition_map):
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],value_serializer=json_serializer)
    exchange = ccxt.pro.kraken({
        'enableRateLimit': True,
        'rateLimit': 1000
    })
    while True:
        snapshot = await exchange.watch_order_book(symbol,10)
        result = producer.send("kraken-orderbook",snapshot,partition=symbols_partition_map[symbol])
        print(snapshot)

def run_kraken_feed(symbols_partition_map):

    try:
        admin = KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

        topic = NewTopic(name='kraken-orderbook',
                            num_partitions=len(symbols_partition_map),
                            replication_factor=1)
        admin.create_topics([topic])
    except Exception:
        pass

    processes = []
    for symbol in symbols_partition_map.keys():
        p = mp.Process(target=asyncio.run, args=(subscribe_orderbook(symbol,symbols_partition_map),))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()


def load_symbols_partition_map():
    with open('kraken_config.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    symbol_dict = {symbol: number for symbol, number in data.items()}
    return symbol_dict

# symbols to subscribe
symbols = load_symbols_partition_map()
run_kraken_feed(symbols)
```

However, I want to change this to create a number of processes based on the number of CPU cores, and then distribute the WebSocket tasks across these processes. I want each process to have its own event loop and handle a specific number of symbols.

As you can see this is not good because if the symbols are greater than number of cores then this is bad.

How can I accomplish this in Python, without using any external libraries? And how can I distribute the symbols to each process in a systematic way?

Thank you for any help or guidance!

please help thanks! sd